# comparing the values of two columns in a table in two different database in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

i have 2 datbases A and B  with tables AC and BD.table AC has a column  ACcol  and BD table has a column  BDcol.

i want to move all the records in ACcol to BDcol with ACcol='admin'.

can anyone help me in doing this?

Comment: Please clarify - do you want to insert or compare? Please provide more detail and possibly table structures.

Comment: i want to get all records in ACcol with value 'admin' to be inserted in to BDcol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an account which has access to both databases, and the tables have the same schema, try the following :-

```
INSERT INTO B.dbo.BD 
SELECT * FROM A.dbo.AB a WHERE A.dbo.AB.col = 'admin'
```

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO B.dbo.BD ( col1, col2, col3 )
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM A.dbo.AB a WHERE A.dbo.AB.col = 'admin'
```

The key is to properly qualify the databases you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at **Sql Server Four Part Naming**

- [SQL Server Four-part naming](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1095)
- [Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions
  (Transact-SQL) : Multipart Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx)
- [Using Synonyms in SQL Server
  2005](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3613301/Using-Synonyms-in-SQL-Server-2005)
- [SQL SERVER – 2005 – Introduction and
  Explanation to SYNONYM – Helpful
  T-SQL Feature for Developer](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/07/sql-server-2005-introduction-and-explanation-to-synonym-helpful-t-sql-feature-for-developer/)